# RTSP on Jelly bean not working

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem with a streaming live video. I'm trying to stream live content to android phones over rtsp. Everything is working fine until a tested my app on Samsung Galaxy 3 with 4.1.1 OS. Samsung is not a problem, because stream has worked before the update (when OS was 4.0.4). My guess is that they messed up something with h264 codecs.
I send stream to a server from a flash application with a video encoded with H264 and audio SPEEX. On a server i use a stream and encode audio to AAC with a ffmpeg and now it is ready for android phones to receive it.

But what is going on now: Same stream we can see on all phones from 2.2 to 4.0.4, but on a 4.1.1 video is corrupted. Audio seems ok...I presume that they change something about h264 decoding, but i don't know what...

Does anybody have the same problem? Or have a solution for my?

I play video vith a videoView on android like this:

```
private void playStream(String url){
    try{       
            video.setVideoPath(" rtsp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1935/APPNAME/pprogramer");
        video.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }catch (Exception exc) {            
        finish();
    }   
}

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
```

Comment: its debatable that you can get decent rtsp streaming on android using any of the supplied components, we got frustrated and just went the ffmpeg approach, take a look at dolphin player its a good sample of what you can do with ffmpeg. just google for it, I don't recall the website.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Did you found any solutions for the problem? If yes, please update your solution here..